# Laravel + Ajax - How to query items by query string from GET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

So I have a products page with different products. There I have some checkboxes for color and size. On checkbox change I want to make an ajax call to my Laravel controller with the needed colors and sizes to query the products and return them back as json and just change the old products with my new ones using javascript. When copying/pasting the full url in another tab, I want to get the products page with the queried products. How can I do that? Here is my code:

```
 <ul class="color-list">
   @foreach($availableColors as $color)
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="color" value="{{ $color->name }}"></li>
    @endforeach
```

```
@foreach($availableSizes as $size)
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="size" value="{{ $size }}">{{ $size }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('/products/{gender}/{subcategory_name}', [
'uses' => 'ProductsController@showProducts',
'as' => 'products']);
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function showProducts($gender, $subcategory_name)
{
    $subcategory = Subcategory::where('name', $subcategory_name)->first();
    $gender = Gender::where('gender', $gender)->first();

    $availableSubcategories = $this->getAvailableSubcategories($subcategory->category->id);
    $availableColors = $this->getAvailableColors($gender, $subcategory);
    $availableSizes = $this->getAvailableSizes($gender, $subcategory);
    $priceRange = $this->getPriceRange($gender, $subcategory);

    return view('products', [
        'gender' => $gender,
        'subcategory' => $subcategory,
        'availableSubcategories' => $availableSubcategories,
        'availableColors' => $availableColors,
        'availableSizes' => $availableSizes,
        'priceRange' => $priceRange
    ]);
}
```

Code, advice, solutions would be appriciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you get this sorted?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I'd maybe look at using `Session` or `Cache`. I wouldn't manipulate the url (it's ugly and can be modified by user).

So in your controller method (note the Request injection):

```
public function showProducts(Request $request, $gender, $subcategory_name)
{
    // if a session already exists, clear it
    if ($request->session()->has('some_name'))
        $request->session()->forget('some_name');

    // your current logic
    ...

    // store new session ($products = save products array to variable)
    $request->session()->put('some_name', $products);
}
```

Then in your view check if session exists:

```
if (Session::has('some_name')) {
    @foreach(Session('some_name') as $some_name)
        ...
    @endforeach
}
else {
    ...
}
```

You could even do a ternary on your loops, etc:

```
@foreach(((Session::has('some_name')) ? Session('some_name')['available_sizes'] : $availableSizes) as $size)
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="size" value="{{ $size }}">{{ $size }</li>
@endforeach
```

None of this was tested. I just wrote it out by hand. But it should give you an idea to work with!

Answer (score 0):

You need to manipulate the browser history of the browser by calling history.pushState to modify the url without reloading the whole page every ajax call request.

Check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API or you can use this javascript plugin https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/